# Can't connect to proftpd FTP server from the internet

Tags: networking, ftp, proftpd

I am trying to connect to an ftp server that I configure myself. Locally it works fine, but when I try to connect through the internet by entering the domain, I get the following error:

```
Status: Resolving the address of domain.cl
Status: Connecting to 111.11.111.111:21 ...
Status: Connection established, waiting for the welcome message ...
Status: Initializing TLS ...
Status: Verifying certificate ...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Registered in
Status: Retrieving the directory listing ...
Command: PWD
Answer: 257 "/" is the current directory
Command: TYPE I
Answer: 200 Type set to I
Command: PASV
Answer: 227 Entering Passive Mode (164,77,132,121,236.77).
Command: MLSD
Error: Could not establish data connection: ECONNREFUSED - Connection 
rejected by server
```

From what I see the server connects to the directory and then the server rejects the connection.

I am using proftpd, the ports are unlocked, I have tried it in all modes, passive, active, etc.

In the proftp log it appears to me that the connection is correct, but at the time of using it in Filezilla or in any other application, you cannot connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a firewall problem.

Either on your side or on the other. Remember that the FTP data ports (those who create the directory list and so on) are created in the range from 1024 to 65535 unless you restrict them to a specific range in the `proftpd`config file.

So you also have to open these ports in your firewall. In `iptables` there is a kernel module called `iptables ip_conntrack_ftp` that does that. It does intelligent *connection tracking*. I don't know how `ufw` does it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

I have an echo form in php that I made to upload images to ftp, for now just enter create the folder and upload a blank text file. I opened the range of ports you told me on the router and I run out of internet

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "run out of internet".

Comment: the internet stopped working

Comment: Because there's TLS, netfilter/conntrack ftp helper can't work. perhaps http://proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_PassivePorts.html + matching firewall holes could.